# C# WinForms ListBox SelectedIndex Equivalent in ListView?

Tags: c#

What is ListBox SelectedIndex Equivalent in ListView ?
How i can write the below code in ListView ?

```
if(listbox.SelectedIndex == -1)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to check if you have an item selected

```
if(listview.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
{ 

}
```

or

```
if(listview.SelectedIndices.Count > 0) 
{ 

}
```

If multisect is true you could have more than one element in this collections else only the Item selected